# How to pass file with webclient to webservice in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webclient

I want pass a file from controller to web service use webclient.How can i pass my file as multipart/form-data??

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateSliders create, HttpPostedFileBase imgUp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            string url = "MYURL";
            webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:Password"));
            webclient.Headers.Add("Request-type", "edit-sliders");
            webclient.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            ///What should i do for pass myfile??

        }

        return View();
    }
```